# Give example(s) where all roots of $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ do not lie on $y= x$ or $y=-x$

Tags: functions, inverse-function

If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,f(x)=x|x|$ and $g: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R, g(x)=-x|x|$ then all three roots of $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ and $g(x)=g^{-1}(x)$ lie on $y=x$ and $y=-x$, respectively.

It will be interesting to have concrete example(s) of $h: A \to B$ where  all roots of $ h(x)=h^{-1}(x)$ do not lie on $y= x$ or $y=-x$. Can you suggest one?

**Edit** Please do not consider the case(s) of no real rootroot and self inverse functions.

Comment: $h(x) = x+1$, all roots of $h(x)=h^{-1}(x)$ do not lie on $y=\pm x$, and simultaneously all roots of $h(x)=h^{-1}(x)$ lie on $y=\pm x$.

Comment: You took a trivial example where the said eqn doesn't have any root. Thanks for your interest. Now I edit it to ward of no root situation.

Comment: For sets $A=B=\mathbb R\setminus\{-1,0,1\}$, $h(x)=1/x$, some and all roots of $h(x)=h^{-1}(x)$ do not lie on $y=\pm x$.

Comment: Ok, so I will now reedit my question. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use : the graph of a function and its inverse are obtained by reflection about the y=x axis ?

Comment: Yes, this is always true.

Comment: Why someone gave $-1$ vote to such  an exploratory question? Its answer given by the OP given below is even more exciting and novel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sets $A=B=\mathbb R\setminus\{0,1\}$, $h:A\to B$,

$$h(x)= \begin{cases}
\frac 1x & x>0 \land x\ne 1\\
2x & x< 0
\end{cases},$$

some and all roots of $h(x)=h^{-1}(x)$ do not lie on $y=x$ or $y=-x$.

$h$ is not a self-inverse function.

Comment: You have used one piece as a self inverse function. Please see my edit.

Comment: @ZAhmed A restriction of $h$ is a self-inverse function, but $h$ is not.

Comment: But yours is a smart choice, so +1.

Comment: @ZAhmed Let $S$ be the set of roots $\{x\mid h(x)=h^{-1}(x)\}$, which is not empty. Your required $h$ must have some restrictions that is self-inverse, for example by restricting to $S$.

Answer (score 3):

A continuous one piece function $f:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty), f(x)=(0.01)^x$ is a bijection

and its inverse is $f^{-1}:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty), f(x)=\log_{0.01} x$

See in the fig. below, the equation $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ has three roots all of them
do not fall on $y=x$ or $y=-x$. Here, $f(x)$ is blue, $f^{-1}(x)$ is red and $y=x$ is green.
[image]

Comment: Very nice example and figure!

Comment: But is it really true that "all of [the three roots] do not fall on $y=x$ or $y=-x$"? Some of the roots do fall on $y=x$ or $y=-x$, in particular the root near $x\approx 0.27799\ldots$ on the green $y=x$.

Comment: It turns out that if point (a.b)  lies on them commonly then (b, a) will also lie on them. Then there are cases when a=b=c meaning (c, c) lies on them. Next, ab<0 or ab>0. It seems if there are roots then (c, c) is necessarily a root which lies on $y=x$.

Comment: You may give +1 to the question it self  it will help many who could not understand!

Comment: Yea, if $a\ne b$, then one of $(a,b)$ or $(b,a)$ is above $y=x$ and the other is below $y=x$. If $f$ is continuous and passes through both $(a,b), (b,a)$ then $y=f(x)$ must cross $y=x$ somewhere. So "all of them [the roots] do not fall on $y=x$ or $y=-x$" fails. But continuity is *not* required by the question.

Answer (score -1):

If $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ then I'd expect $f(f(x))=x$. By definition if $f(f(x))=x$ and $f(x) \ne x$ then $x$ is a periodic point for $f$ of prime period $2$.

There are many classes of functions that give solutions. For example suppose $g_\lambda(x)=\lambda \cdot x\cdot(1-x)$. What is the smallest real number for which $g_\lambda(x) =x$ has a solution in the reals? What about $g_\lambda(g_\lambda(x))=x$? Values of lambda in this example or $c$ in the other polynomial example are parameter values which determine whether there are fixed points, points of period two, period 4, and so on. I'd expect this to give you what you are looking for. Topics associated with this are Bifurcation Diagrams as well as the above mentioned Periodic Points.

$f(f(x))=x$

Let $ f(x)=x^2+c$

$f(f(x))= (x^2+c)^2+c = x^4+2cx^2+c^2+c$

$x^4+2cx^2 -x+c^2+c=0$

$(x^2-x+c)(Ax^2+Bx+C)=x^4+2cx^2-x+c^2+c$

$A=1. $

$B-A=0\implies B=1.$

$C-B+Ac=2c\implies C=c+1$

$(x^2-x+c)(x^2+x+c+1)$

$x=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{-3-4c}}{2}$

$f(x)=\frac{ -2-4c \mp 2\sqrt{-3-4c}}{4}= \frac{-1 \mp \sqrt{-3-4c}}{2}-c \ne x$

Comment: Eventually, would you please write your answer as $F: A \to B, F(x)=?$ and then $F^{-1}: B\to A, F^{-1}(x)=?;$ defining sets and forms of the functions.

Comment: My general idea is find points of a function of prime period two. By definition $f(f(\alpha))=\alpha$ but $f(\alpha)\ne \alpha$, for that would be a fixed point, i.e. a point of prime period one.  If $f(f(\alpha))=\alpha$, then $f(\alpha)=f^{-1}(\alpha)$. The scenario I present doesn't seem to be an example or I made a mistake somewhere. Trying to figure that out.